Are there any commercially made optical fibers which are made specifically to have very low microphonic properties for application in interferometry
Are there any commercially made optical fibers which are made specifically to have very low microphonic properties for applications in interferometry. While building a fiber optic interferometer I noticed that fibers of different manufacturers exhibit varying sensitivity to vibration and I would like to know if any company manufactures fibers specifically designed to have low microphonic properties.
